# Why is this returning as a floated decimal value?

Tags: javascript

The last line reads "The grand total is 41.300000000000004". I've been running it in repl.it.

```js
var groceryList = [
    {food: "Mangos", price: 3.56},
    {food: "Grapes", price: 4.23},
    {food: "Chicken", price: 10.98},
    {food: "Sweet Potatoes", price: 7.94},
    {food: "Asst. Nuts", price: 6.54},
    {food: "Yogurt", price: 5.32},
    {food: "Papya", price: 2.73}
    ];

function shopping(items){
    console.log (items.food + " = " + items.price + ".");
    }
var grocery;
var total=0;
for ( grocery in  groceryList){
     
    total=total+groceryList[grocery].price;
    shopping(groceryList[grocery]);
}

    console.log("The grand total is " + total);
```

Comment: Take a look at this web-site - http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3439981/2549512)

Comment: Use the value in cents as an integer; for instance, {food: "Mangos", price: 356}.  Then divide by 100 for display; or better yet, just shift the decimal point.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var groceryList = [
    {food: "Mangos", price: 3.56},
    {food: "Grapes", price: 4.23},
    {food: "Chicken", price: 10.98},
    {food: "Sweet Potatoes", price: 7.94},
    {food: "Asst. Nuts", price: 6.54},
    {food: "Yogurt", price: 5.32},
    {food: "Papya", price: 2.73}
    ];
function shopping(items){
    console.log (items.food + " = " + items.price + ".");
}
var total = 0;
for(var i=0; i < groceryList.length; i++){
    total += groceryList[i].price;
}
console.log(Math.round(total));
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @BigPapa copy and paste the above code in if your still looking for the answer, you should use the Math.round() method.